# formular1c1 with variable error 1004

Tags: variables, excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following code:

```
For i = 1 To F.Rows.Count
Formula = "=" & F(i, 1)
Rt.FormulaR1C1 = Formula
Next i
```

I placed string into F(i, 1):

```
F(i, 1) = TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IF(OR(RC[4]="""",RC[4]=""text""),
""text"",RC[2]&IF(AND(RC[3]<>""text"",RC[2]<>""text""),"","","""")
&"" ""&RC[3]&"" ""&RC[4]&"" ""&RC[5]&"" ""&RC[6]&"" ""&RC[7]),""text"",""""))
```

My formula is too complex. But I can't figure the problem in sintax. Please, help.

Comment: Edit: I think your formula should be like this: `TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IF(OR(RC[4]={"""",""text""}),""text"",RC[2]&IF(AND(RC[3]<>""text"",RC[2]<>""text""),"","","""") &"" ""&RC[3]&"" ""&RC[4]&"" ""&RC[5]&"" ""&RC[6]&"" ""&RC[7]),""text"",""""))`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. I just removed double quotes to single. "" → "
I don't know why, but it works. Final formula was:

```
F(i, 1) = TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(IF(OR(RC[4]="",RC[4]="text"),"text",
RC[2]&IF(AND(RC[3]<>"text",RC[2]<>"text"),",","")
&" "&RC[3]&" "&RC[4]&" "&RC[5]&" "&RC[6]&" "&RC[7]),"text",""))
```

Does anyone know why it works? Thanks!

Comment: Silly me - you only need to double the quotes if they are inside a literal quoted string.